# Blurrier or more blurry?

Tags: single-word-requests, comparatives

I am not sure about this particular word, the sentence is the following 'Increase it for more blurry(ier) effect.'

Answer (score 0):

From [Merriam Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blurry):

> **blurry** adjective
>
> blurrier; blurriest ...

So you sentence would be 'Increase it for a blurrier effect.'

Comment: Note that this is only the case if you can insert the indefinite article, making the comparative the modifier of _effect_ (i.e., ‘for a different effect which is blurrier than the effect currently applied’). An alternative possibility, which does not require the article, is “increase it for more blurry effect”, taking _more_ as a measurement of the amount of blurry effect to be applied (i.e., ‘for a greater amount/intensity of the same blurry effect which is currently applied’).

Answer (score 0):

You could punt and just use "Increase for a more blurred effect."